# Finding AC equivalent seen between two nodes of a BJT Amplifier

Tags: circuit-analysis, amplifier, bjt

In the textbook, `Electronic Devices and Circuit Theory, 11th Edition by Boylestead and Nashelsky`, on page 566, the lower cutoff frequency is derived for a voltage divider BJT circuit. The circuit used is shown below.

[image: Voltage Divider BJT Circuit]

The lower cutoff frequency of \$C_E\$ is to be found. For this, they first find the equivalent AC circuit as seen from \$C_E\$.

[image: AC Equivalent Circuit]

My question is, how did the obtain this expression?: $$\dfrac{R_1||R_2}{\beta}+r_e$$

I understand that they applied Thevenin's thorem, but I'm stil not sure how this expression comes out. Also, doesn't \$R_C\$ play a role here?

Comment: Try read this https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/365561/output-impedance-seen-by-the-load-in-this-emitter-follower/365586#365586 or this https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/429716/arriving-at-a-wrong-output-impedance-for-a-bjt-emitter-follower-configuration-ci/429726#429726

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just draw the small signal model of the circuit to calculate the impedance seen at the emitter. Assuming a resistance \$r_b\$ is connected to the base, the impedance is calculated as:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7bLfN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Apply KCL at the emitter to give:

$$\beta i_b + i_b +i_x = \frac{v_x}{R_E}$$

Apply KVL in the emitter-base loop:

$$v_x + (\beta + 1)i_br_e + i_br_b = 0$$
$$\implies i_b = -\frac{v_x}{(\beta + 1)r_e + r_b}$$

Putting it in the first equation,
$$-(\beta + 1)\frac{v_x}{(\beta + 1)r_e + r_b} + i_x = \frac{v_x}{R_E}$$
$$\implies \frac{i_x}{v_x} = \frac{1}{R_E} + \frac{1}{r_e + \frac{r_b}{\beta + 1}}$$
Thus equivalent impedance is \$R_E||(r_e+\frac{r_b}{\beta + 1})\$.
The base resistance \$r_b\$ for your case is \$R_1||R_2\$ which gives the expression you want (\$\beta >> 1\$).
I want to emphasize that the calculated base resistance is valid if the transistor is driven by a current source. In case of voltage driven input, the equivalent base resistance would be zero. Note that BJT is a current controlled current source, so it's input is usually a current source.

Answer (score 1):

Looking from the emitter terminal, collector is a *current source* whose current cannot be changed. It offers infinite resistance and acts as an open circuit:

\$R = \dfrac{\Delta V}{\Delta I} = \dfrac{\Delta V}{ 0} = \infty\$

Thus \$R_C\$ doesn't affect the impedance seen from emitter side.

---

You can obtain the resistance of a block by measuring the voltage and current. Suppose you put a current source \$i\$ at the emitter terminal. The **voltage** developed across the current source will be \$ir_e + \dfrac{i}{\beta}(R_1\| R_2)\$. Divide by the current to get the resistance seen at the emitter terminal.

Here \$r_e\$ is the resistane of transistor's base emitter junction.

Comment: Comment: The quantity re is NOT the resistance of the base-emitter junction. Instead, it is the inverse of the transconductance re=1/gm=VT/Ic (VT=temperature voltage). More than that, the influence of the ohmic resistor RE was forgotten (it is in parallel to the given expression).

Comment: @LvW oh my textbook defined it as ac resistance of the emitter diode. It wouldn't be surprising for my textbook to be wrong though. It oversimplifies a lot https://prnt.sc/rl843t

Comment: The input resistance at the emitter involves 1/gm - that is for sure. Please, look at the two links provided by the member G36 directly after the question. by the way - I do not like using the quantity re at all because - in fact - it is NOT a resistance. It is just an expression (unit voltage/current) for 1/gm , but it should not be modelled as a resistance. Here we have a good example how such a view can lead to severe misunderstandings.

Comment: Ah I see your point. So it is not actually any physical resistance of the emitter diode. It is the inverse of transconductance and thus has units of resistnace. Thanks @LvW :)

Comment: ....I just had a look on your linked drawing.....OK, now I know what you mean (resp. your book). But - for my opinion, the expression "emitter diode" is rather misleading. A diode has two nodes ! The problem is as follows: The voltage Vbe (between node E and node B) allows a current that goes NOT through node B. Hence, it is not correct to say that re is the resistance of the diode between B and E. Voltage and current are not defined between the same two nodes - hence it is not a "resistance".

Comment: The resistance of the transistor`s base-emitter junction is h11 (or hie, or rbe)

Comment: @LvW point noted. Vbe causes collector current too so I see how it is more complicated than a simple resistor. You're so awesome! Thank you so much really appreciate it :D

Comment: To make it clear: The defintion of the quantity to be used for the calculation (as shown in your book as a voltage-current curve, linked by you) is correct. But this quantity should not be called "resistance of the B-E diode". It is nothing else than d(Vbe)/d(Ie)=1/gm  (assuming Ie=Ic)

Answer (score 1):

I think that expression should actually be:-

((R1//R2//Rs)/Beta) + re where Rs = signal source resistance

In the ideal case of Rs = 0 the left hand term disappears and the equation reduces to re.

Comment: Just for clarification: re=1/gm=VT/IC (VT: temperature voltage VT)

Answer (score 0):

Well, we have the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f59O5W.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When analyzing a transistor we need to use the following [relations](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/transistor/tran_2.html):

- $$\text{I}_\text{E}=\text{I}_\text{B}+\text{I}_\text{C}\tag1$$
- Transistor gain \$\beta\$:
  $$\beta=\frac{\text{I}_\text{C}}{\text{I}_\text{B}}\tag2$$
- Emitter voltage:
  $$\text{V}_\text{E}=\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2\tag3$$

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff's_current_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_2=\text{I}_1+\text{I}_9\\
\\
0=\text{I}_8+\text{I}_9+\text{I}_{10}\\
\\
\text{I}_{10}=\text{I}_6+\text{I}_{11}\\
\\
\text{I}_7=\text{I}_5+\text{I}_{11}\\
\\
\text{I}_\text{E}=\text{I}_6+\text{I}_8\\
\\
\text{I}_1+\text{I}_3=\text{I}_\text{B}+\text{I}_2\\
\\
\text{I}_4=\text{I}_\text{C}+\text{I}_7\\
\\
\text{I}_5=\text{I}_3+\text{I}_4
\end{cases}\tag4
$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{V}_\text{x}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\frac{\text{V}_\text{y}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_4=\frac{\text{V}_\text{y}-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_4}\\
\\
\text{I}_5=\frac{\text{V}_3-\text{V}_4}{\text{R}_5}\\
\\
\text{I}_6=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_6}\\
\\
\text{I}_7=\frac{\text{V}_4}{\text{R}_7}\\
\\
\text{I}_8=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_8}
\end{cases}\tag5
$$

Solving these systems of equations is possible, I used Mathematica:

```
In[1]:=FullSimplify[
 Solve[{VE == V1 - V2, β == IC/IB, IE == IB + IC, I2 == I1 + I9,
    0 == I8 + I9 + I10, I10 == I6 + I11, I7 == I5 + I11, 
   IE == I6 + I8, I1 + I3 == IB + I2, I4 == IC + I7, I5 == I3 + I4, 
   I1 == (Vx - V1)/R1, I2 == (V1)/R2, I3 == (Vy - V1)/R3, 
   I4 == (Vy - V3)/R4, I5 == (V3 - V4)/R5, I6 == (V2)/R6, 
   I7 == (V4)/R7, I8 == (V2)/R8}, {IB, IC, IE, I1, I2, I3, I4, I5, I6,
    I7, I8, I9, I10, I11, V1, V2, V3, V4}]]

Out[1]={{IB -> -(((R6 + R8) (R1 (R2 + R3) VE + R2 R3 (VE - Vx) - 
          R1 R2 Vy))/(R2 R3 R6 R8 (1 + β) + 
        R1 (R2 R3 (R6 + R8) + R2 R6 R8 (1 + β) + 
           R3 R6 R8 (1 + β)))), 
  IC -> -(((R6 + R8) (R1 (R2 + R3) VE + R2 R3 (VE - Vx) - 
          R1 R2 Vy) β)/(R2 R3 R6 R8 (1 + β) + 
        R1 (R2 R3 (R6 + R8) + R2 R6 R8 (1 + β) + 
           R3 R6 R8 (1 + β)))), 
  IE -> -(((R6 + R8) (R1 (R2 + R3) VE + R2 R3 (VE - Vx) - 
          R1 R2 Vy) (1 + β))/(R2 R3 R6 R8 (1 + β) + 
        R1 (R2 R3 (R6 + R8) + R2 R6 R8 (1 + β) + 
           R3 R6 R8 (1 + β)))), 
  I1 -> (-R2 R3 (R6 + R8) (VE - Vx) + R3 R6 R8 Vx (1 + β) + 
      R2 R6 R8 (Vx - Vy) (1 + β))/(R2 R3 R6 R8 (1 + β) + 
      R1 (R2 R3 (R6 + R8) + R2 R6 R8 (1 + β) + 
         R3 R6 R8 (1 + β))), 
  I2 -> (R1 R3 (R6 + R8) VE + R3 R6 R8 Vx (1 + β) + 
      R1 R6 R8 Vy (1 + β))/(R2 R3 R6 R8 (1 + β) + 
      R1 (R2 R3 (R6 + R8) + R2 R6 R8 (1 + β) + 
         R3 R6 R8 (1 + β))), 
  I3 -> (-R1 R2 (R6 + R8) (VE - Vy) - 
      R2 R6 R8 (Vx - Vy) (1 + β) + 
      R1 R6 R8 Vy (1 + β))/(R2 R3 R6 R8 (1 + β) + 
      R1 (R2 R3 (R6 + R8) + R2 R6 R8 (1 + β) + 
         R3 R6 R8 (1 + β))), 
  I4 -> (R2 R6 R8 (R5 (Vx - Vy) + R3 Vy) + 
      R2 (-R3 R7 (R6 + R8) (VE - Vx) + R5 R6 R8 (Vx - Vy) + 
         R3 R6 R8 Vy) β + 
      R1 ((R3 - 
            R5) R6 R8 Vy - (R3 R7 (R6 + R8) VE + (-R3 + 
               R5) R6 R8 Vy) β + 
         R2 (R5 (R6 + R8) (VE - Vy) + R3 R6 Vy + (R3 + R6) R8 Vy - 
            R7 (R6 + R8) VE β + 
            R6 R7 Vy β + (R6 + R7) R8 Vy β)))/((R4 + R5 + 
        R7) (R2 R3 R6 R8 (1 + β) + 
        R1 (R2 R3 (R6 + R8) + R2 R6 R8 (1 + β) + 
           R3 R6 R8 (1 + β)))), 
  I5 -> (R2 R6 R8 (-(R4 + R7) Vx + (R3 + R4 + R7) Vy) + 
      R2 (-R3 R7 (R6 + R8) (VE - Vx) + R3 R6 R8 Vy + 
         R6 (R4 + R7) R8 (-Vx + Vy)) β + 
      R1 (R6 (R3 + R4 + R7) R8 Vy - R3 R7 (R6 + R8) VE β + 
         R6 (R3 + R4 + R7) R8 Vy β + 
         R2 (-R4 (R6 + R8) (VE - Vy) + R3 R6 Vy + R3 R8 Vy - 
            R7 R8 (VE - Vy) (1 + β) - 
            R6 (R7 VE - (R7 + R8) Vy) (1 + β))))/((R4 + R5 + 
        R7) (R2 R3 R6 R8 (1 + β) + 
        R1 (R2 R3 (R6 + R8) + R2 R6 R8 (1 + β) + 
           R3 R6 R8 (1 + β)))), 
  I6 -> -((R8 (R1 (R2 + R3) VE + R2 R3 (VE - Vx) - 
          R1 R2 Vy) (1 + β))/(R2 R3 R6 R8 (1 + β) + 
        R1 (R2 R3 (R6 + R8) + R2 R6 R8 (1 + β) + 
           R3 R6 R8 (1 + β)))), 
  I7 -> (R2 R6 R8 (R5 (Vx - Vy) + R3 Vy) + 
      R2 (R3 (R4 + R5) (R6 + R8) (VE - Vx) + R5 R6 R8 (Vx - Vy) + 
         R3 R6 R8 Vy) β + 
      R1 (R3 R6 R8 Vy + 
         R3 ((R4 + R5) (R6 + R8) VE + R6 R8 Vy) β - 
         R5 R6 R8 Vy (1 + β) + 
         R2 (R6 R8 Vy + R3 (R6 + R8) Vy + 
            R4 (R6 + R8) (VE - Vy) β + R6 R8 Vy β + 
            R5 (R6 + R8) (VE - Vy) (1 + β))))/((R4 + R5 + 
        R7) (R2 R3 R6 R8 (1 + β) + 
        R1 (R2 R3 (R6 + R8) + R2 R6 R8 (1 + β) + 
           R3 R6 R8 (1 + β)))), 
  I8 -> -((R6 (R1 (R2 + R3) VE + R2 R3 (VE - Vx) - 
          R1 R2 Vy) (1 + β))/(R2 R3 R6 R8 (1 + β) + 
        R1 (R2 R3 (R6 + R8) + R2 R6 R8 (1 + β) + 
           R3 R6 R8 (1 + β)))), 
  I9 -> (R1 R3 (R6 + R8) VE + R2 R3 (R6 + R8) (VE - Vx) - 
      R2 R6 R8 (Vx - Vy) (1 + β) + 
      R1 R6 R8 Vy (1 + β))/(R2 R3 R6 R8 (1 + β) + 
      R1 (R2 R3 (R6 + R8) + R2 R6 R8 (1 + β) + 
         R3 R6 R8 (1 + β))), 
  I10 -> (R1 R2 R6 (VE - Vy) (1 + β) + 
      R2 R6 R8 (Vx - Vy) (1 + β) - R1 R6 R8 Vy (1 + β) - 
      R2 R3 (VE - Vx) (R8 - R6 β) + 
      R1 R3 VE (-R8 + R6 β))/(R2 R3 R6 R8 (1 + β) + 
      R1 (R2 R3 (R6 + R8) + R2 R6 R8 (1 + β) + 
         R3 R6 R8 (1 + β))), 
  I11 -> (R2 R6 R8 (Vx - Vy) + 
      R2 (R3 (R6 + R8) (VE - Vx) + R6 R8 (Vx - Vy)) β + 
      R1 (R3 R6 VE β + R3 R8 VE β + 
         R2 (R6 + R8) (VE - Vy) (1 + β) - 
         R6 R8 Vy (1 + β)))/(R2 R3 R6 R8 (1 + β) + 
      R1 (R2 R3 (R6 + R8) + R2 R6 R8 (1 + β) + 
         R3 R6 R8 (1 + β))), 
  V1 -> (R2 (R1 R3 (R6 + R8) VE + R3 R6 R8 Vx (1 + β) + 
        R1 R6 R8 Vy (1 + β)))/(R2 R3 R6 R8 (1 + β) + 
      R1 (R2 R3 (R6 + R8) + R2 R6 R8 (1 + β) + 
         R3 R6 R8 (1 + β))), 
  V2 -> -((R6 R8 (R1 (R2 + R3) VE + R2 R3 (VE - Vx) - 
          R1 R2 Vy) (1 + β))/(R2 R3 R6 R8 (1 + β) + 
        R1 (R2 R3 (R6 + R8) + R2 R6 R8 (1 + β) + 
           R3 R6 R8 (1 + β)))), 
  V3 -> (R2 (R3 R4 R7 (R6 + R8) (VE - Vx) β - 
         R4 R5 R6 R8 (Vx - Vy) (1 + β) + 
         R3 R6 (R5 + R7) R8 Vy (1 + β)) + 
      R1 (R3 R6 (R5 + R7) R8 Vy + R3 R4 R7 (R6 + R8) VE β + 
         R3 R6 (R5 + R7) R8 Vy β + 
         R4 R5 R6 R8 Vy (1 + β) - 
         R2 R4 (R6 + R8) (VE - Vy) (R5 - R7 β) + 
         R2 (R5 + R7) Vy (R3 (R6 + R8) + R6 R8 (1 + β))))/((R4 +
         R5 + R7) (R2 R3 R6 R8 (1 + β) + 
        R1 (R2 R3 (R6 + R8) + R2 R6 R8 (1 + β) + 
           R3 R6 R8 (1 + β)))), 
  V4 -> (R7 (R2 R6 R8 (R5 (Vx - Vy) + R3 Vy) + 
        R2 (R3 (R4 + R5) (R6 + R8) (VE - Vx) + R5 R6 R8 (Vx - Vy) + 
           R3 R6 R8 Vy) β + 
        R1 (R3 R6 R8 Vy + 
           R3 ((R4 + R5) (R6 + R8) VE + R6 R8 Vy) β - 
           R5 R6 R8 Vy (1 + β) + 
           R2 (R6 R8 Vy + R3 (R6 + R8) Vy + 
              R4 (R6 + R8) (VE - Vy) β + R6 R8 Vy β + 
              R5 (R6 + R8) (VE - Vy) (1 + β)))))/((R4 + R5 + 
        R7) (R2 R3 R6 R8 (1 + β) + 
        R1 (R2 R3 (R6 + R8) + R2 R6 R8 (1 + β) + 
           R3 R6 R8 (1 + β))))}}
```

> Now, I've a question for you: what do you mean by 'The lower cutoff frequency of CE is to be found'? The lower cutoff frequency of a component is a weird question.

Comment: Yes - you are right. But to me it was clear that the cut-off frequency CAUSED by CE and the surrounding resistive elements is wanted.

Comment: @LvW  So if I understand correctly, we want to find the -3dB point (3dB lower than the maximum voltage possible for a given frequency) of the voltage V2 in my circuit?

Comment: No - your circuit does not represent the original circuit. I do not see any capacitor.

Comment: @LvW Yes I understand that, but I can set it to be one using R1=1/(sC1). If I do so is that than what you want to find that -3dB point?

Comment: For a first-order RC section the -3dB cutoff is always the inverse of the corresponding time constant RC. If we feed a test current into the emitter node and measure the corresponding voltage at this node, the -3dB frequency is defined where this voltage is 3dB lower than the maximum (for very low frequencies)

Comment: What I mean by the lower cutoff frequency of CE is basically the frequency at whichc the voltage across it would be 1/root2 the input voltage. Or, as you said, the -3dB point for the component.